# how to use typescript Compiler API to get normal function info, eg: returnType/parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

```
/**
 * class of User
 */
class User {
    /**
     * constructor
     * @param name c-name
     */
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
    /**
     * property name
     */
    private name: string
    /**
     * setName
     * @param name f-name
     */
    public setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

I saw the [Typescript Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) and I can get the constructor's info, eg: returnType/parameters.

```
[
    {
        "name": "User",
        "documentation": "class of User",
        "type": "typeof User",
        "constructors": [
            {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "name",
                        "documentation": "c-name",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "returnType": "User",
                "documentation": "constructor"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but i want t get the infomation of returnType/parameters/documentation on normal function **getName** , how can i do this?

ps:I know the constructor has the signatures, signatures has a function **getReturntype**, but the normal functions has no signatures, so i can not get the info

**thanks!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you know how to get the `MethodDeclaration`, then the following will work:

```
// I'm assuming you know how to get the type checker from the compiler too.
const typeChecker = ...;
// Navigate through the tree to get to the method declaration located in the class.
// This is the node with kind === ts.SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration or
// you can use ts.isMethodDeclaration(node)
const methodDeclaration = ... as ts.MethodDeclaration;

const signature = typeChecker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(methodDeclaration);
const returnType = typeChecker.getReturnTypeOfSignature(signature);
const parameters = methodDeclaration.parameters; // array of Parameters
const docs = methodDeclaration.jsDoc; // array of js docs
```

By the way, you should check out this [AST viewer](http://ts-ast-viewer.com) I wrote. It might help you with some future questions you have. Also, depending on your use case, [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/) which will help make navigating and manipulating the AST a little easier.

Comment: thanks! I like this method :                                                                       
   const signature = checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(method)

Comment: Thanks much for this! It's rather difficult to find documentation on the compiler api... do you know of any case where `getSignatureFromDeclaration` will return `undefined`? I haven't been able to make it happen but it's in the signature...

Comment: @Gerrit0 it's best to look at the source. See `getSignatureFromDeclaration` in [checker.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/checker.ts).

Comment: This seems not to work if the return type is an array of some sort. ```returnType``` is then always ```any```.